# Copy selected cells if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names in a Sheet3, 
Column A:6-33 has the names of some clients
Column B:6-33 empty
Column C:6-33 empty

I also have Sheet4:
column A 5000 client names
column C & F have important data of that client which I need to copy to Column B & C in Sheet3.

So when `Sheet3.Cell Ax == Sheet4.Cell Ax`
`Sheet3.B` & `C` needs to copy the data of `Sheet4.C` & `F`

Somehow I'm not being able to get the loop right.
right now I have tunnel vision and I can't seem to fix this problem.

Comment: I'm only able to get one value only for the first cell that the loop goes through. I can't loop the whole data. I haven't programmed in VB since 2010 and this is killing me -_- . And I'm supposed to have this ready in less then 3 hours.

Comment: You can use vlookup for this - no need for VBA

Comment: I need  to be able to do it with a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim clientrange As Range
Dim searchrange As Range
Dim i As Long

Set clientrange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A6") 'you may have to use sheets("sheet3")
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4) 'you may have to use sheets("sheet4")
    While clientrange.Text <> ""
        'search for clients in sheet4
        For i = 1 To 5000
            If .Range("A" & i) = clientrange.Text Then
                'copy the values
                clientrange.Offset(0, 1) = .Range("C" & i)
                clientrange.Offset(0, 2) = .Range("F" & i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        'go one down
        Set clientrange = clientrange.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
End With
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly. Thank you so much I owe you a coffee.
If I may I would like to ask another question.

for the range i = 1 To 5049  the cell from sheet3 might be == to many cells in sheet4.
How to I count how many times each cell is found in  the sheet4.

Comment: You could add a counter. You would have to remove the "exit for" in that case.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is `VLOOKUP` function:

Sheet 3

- Column B formula (import the formula in Cell B6 and drag down):

`=VLOOKUP(A6,Sheet4!$A$1:$F$5000,3,0)`

- Column C formula (import the formula in Cell C6 and drag down):

`=VLOOKUP(A6,Sheet4!$A$1:$F$5000,6,0)`

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub tes()

     Dim ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
     Dim i As Long
     Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
     Dim arr As Variant
     Dim strValueC As String, strValueF As String

     With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws3 = .Worksheets("Sheet3")
        Set ws4 = .Worksheets("Sheet4")
     End With

     With ws3
        arr = .Range("A6:A33")
        .Range("B6:C33").Clear
     End With

     Set rngSearch = ws4.Range("A1:A5000")

     For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=arr(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

            With ws4
                strValueC = .Range("C" & rngFound.Row).Value
                strValueF = .Range("F" & rngFound.Row).Value
            End With

            With ws3
                .Range("B" & i + 5).Value = strValueC
                .Range("C" & i + 5).Value = strValueF
            End With

        End If

     Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't use VLOOKUP because I need to write a macro and assign it to a Button that when it's clicked it will import that data.

Comment: @ErsonCokaj i have update the answer to use also VBA using `array` & `Find method` which provide a faster result. you could give a test i you want to